# Swift - Firebase observer on .childchanged is not being recognized

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the code below, it will not get executed even if I change the child node called "tokens" in the Firebase via app or directly in Firebase!?

```
handle = ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("tokens").observe(.childChanged, with: { snap in

                print("Changed Token Count: ", snap.value!)

                if snap.value is NSNull {

                    // Child not found

                } else {

                    if (currTokenCount < snap.value as! UInt) {

                        print("Value increased....")

                    } else {

                        print("Value decreased....")

                    }

                }

            }) { (error) in

                print(error.localizedDescription)

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have a data structure like this:

```
Users
  uid1
    tokens: "value of tokens"
```

If you want to listen for changes to `token` of a specific user in the above structure, use a `.value` listener:

```
handle = ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("tokens").observe(.value, with: { snap in

    print("Changed Token Count: ", snap.value!)

    if snap.value is NSNull {
        // Child not found
    } else {
        if (currTokenCount < snap.value as! UInt) {
            print("Value increased....")
        } else {
            print("Value decreased....")
        }
    }
}) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

The .child*`listeners are only used when you have child nodes under`tokens`, like:

```
Users
  uid1
    tokens
      token1: "value of token1"
      token2: "value of token2"
```

Comment: Ahhhhh.... thank you very much I am using the `.value` but I figure the `.childchanged` would incur less activity but thank you for informing me about how `.childchanged` works!!!

Comment: quick question if i have `var handle: UInt = 0` and I want to see if it is null the following code throws a warning... `if handle != null`. Am I missing something? I am using `handle` to remove the observer.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for explaining the difference between **.value** and **.childChanged** at the end!