# Swift -Firebase how to observe multiple posts in tableView cells

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a tableView that has a number of cells for each post. I need to observe changes to a couple of different properties (`availability` && `hours`) and I would like to update them in the specific cells that they relate to. This is what I came up with but I don't think it is the correct way to do it because I only need to listen for changes to the `availability` && `hours` properties.

```
struct Post {
    var postId: String
    var uid: String
    var availability: Bool // this can change
    var hours: String // this can change
}

var arrOfPosts = [Post]() // 1 - n posts

override viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   for post in arrOfPosts {

      let postId = post.postId

      Database....child(postId).observe( .childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in

          let updatedPostId = snapshot.key

          if let indexOfItem = self.arrOfPosts.firstIndex(where: { $0.postId == updatedPostId }) {

              // update post in cell via batchUpdate
          }
      })

      Database....child(postId).observe( .removed, with: { (snapshot) in

          let deletedPostId = snapshot.key

          if let indexOfItem = self.arrOfPosts.firstIndex(where: { $0.postId == deletedPostId }) {

              // remove cell via batchUpdate
          }
      })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct but you need to be specific in path to minimize response load that firebase adds more cost for

```
Database....child("\(postId)/availability")
```

same for `hours`

Comment: For anyone else this answer is correct but when you observe a property you have to use **.value**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53686683/4833705